# SQLite (Flutter) - Sorting Foreign Key By Date

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

For my Flutter app, it has a product database which consist of a primary key ID (product_ID), foreign key ID (user_ID), and date_created.

Goal: I want to sort the rows given a foreign key ID (user_ID) by date (date_created)(least recent to most recent), and then update the product table.

I believe I need to update the `sortedRows`'s product_ID by ascending order to make this work, but I'm not sure how that is done.

I have done the sorting part already:

```
Future<void> filterByDate(String userID) async {
    print("filterByDate()");
    Database? db = await instance.database;
 
 
    // Step 1: Retrieve the sorted rows
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> sortedRows = await db!.rawQuery('''
    SELECT *
    FROM $table
    WHERE ${ProductFields.userID} = ?
    ORDER BY ${ProductFields.timeCreated} ASC
  ''', [userID]);
 
 
    print(sortedRows);
}
```

Here is an example of what I mean.

```
Given user_ID = 234

product table:primary key ID (product_ID) /// foreign key ID (user_ID) /// product_name /// prodate_created

0/// 234 /// car /// May 1

1/// 234 /// plane /// January 1

2 ///543/// shaver ///Oct 1

3/// 234 /// guitar /// Feb 1
```

For my goal, I want the product table to be like this:

```
product table:

primary key ID (product_ID) /// foreign key ID (user_ID) /// date_created

0/// 234 /// plane /// January 1

1/// 234 /// guitar /// Feb 1

2 ///543 /// shaver /// Oct 1

3 /// 234 /// car /// May 1
```

As you can see, the current user with the user ID 234 can now see his created products are sorted by date_created.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: UPDATE: My approach is incorrect. All I have to do is display the list of products from the sorted query that I have gotten from filterByDate().